# How to serialize a list of Enums?

Tags: flutter, serialization, enums

I'm tring to serialize a list of enum values in Flutter, to store in SharedPreferences but I can't get it to work, what am I missing?

I have a Enum:

```
@JsonEnum()
enum MyStepState {
  @JsonValue('indexed') indexed,
  @JsonValue('editing') editing,
  @JsonValue('complete')complete,
  @JsonValue('disabled') disabled,
  @JsonValue('error') error,
}
```

I have a list made up of these enum values:

```
var stepState = [
    MyStepState.indexed,
    MyStepState.indexed,
    MyStepState.indexed,
    MyStepState.indexed
];
```

And I need to serialize this list of enums to store in SharedPreferences

```
final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await preferences.setString('stepState', json.encode(stepState));
```

But it errors at runtime:

```
Exception has occurred.
JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'MyStepState')
```

What do I need to do to encode this list of enums to json?

Comment: You need to run the generator: https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable#running-the-code-generator.

Comment: Sorry, yes I have run the code generator. Just run it again to be sure but I still get the same exception.

Comment: Use the generated code instead of json.encode.